# how to find method in assembly file in hex?

Tags: .net, reflection, hex, .net-assembly

I have a test assembly and I want to find method in file

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public bool get_CreateFlash()
{
    return this.cZBH;
}
```

I use hex editor and template to search

```
2B * 26 16 02 7B * * * * 0A 2B * 06 2A
```

where * is any byte because I do not see exact bytes in tools like ILSpy.

I have found 1500 matches, naturally, it is getter. The different is in 7B * * * *, like this

```
"2B 02 26 16 02 7B 1D 00 00 04 0A 2B 00 06 2A"
"2B 02 26 16 02 7B 1E 00 00 04 0A 2B 00 06 2A"
...
etc.
```

How can I find what I need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use ILDasm (part of the .NET Framework SDK), it will show you the corresponding code bytes.

To show them, you need to select View -> Show Bytes before displaying the method. I put together a small example application to test this, and got the following:

[image: Disassembly of a simple property getter in ILDASM with "Show Bytes" enabled]

In order to use this data it's important to know that the bytes on the left of the "|" appear in-order in the .dll/.exe, and those on the right are encoded in little-endian. With this in mind, I searched the .exe for the following (note that I have highlighted the bytes that are in little-endian order):

> 00 02 7b **03 00 00 04** 0a 2b **00** 06 2a

In my (albeit small) test executable, this sequence of bytes occurred only once.

Note that in the screenshot above, it also indicates the method RVA (Relative Virtual Address). In order to convert this into a file location, you need to determine the layout of the executable file. There are a number of PE tools available, but I used `dumpbin` which comes with Visual Studio to view the PE headers (`dumpbin /headers <your exe name>`). The relevant data for this executable:

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    1824 virtual size
    2000 virtual address (00402000 to 00403823)
    1A00 size of raw data
     200 file pointer to raw data (00000200 to 00001BFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read
```

Here, the `.text` section's virtual address is indicated as 0x2000, and has a virtual size of 0x1824 bytes. Since the method has an RVA of 0x2464, it must reside within this section. The "file pointer to raw data" in the output from `dumpbin` indicates that the section containing our method begins at 0x200 in the executable file, so we can calculate the offset of the method in the executable file as:

```
(Method RVA - Section RVA) + File Location
= (0x2464 - 0x2000) + 0x200
= 0x664
```

Going to location 0x664 in the test executable file, the bytes we were looking for can indeed by seen there (they are not exactly at this location, but a few bytes after it as there is a small method header before the IL bytes).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting and useful description. In my case I use Reflector or ILSpy to reach this method. This is only one way to get it starting from other method. And in this place I see only what Reflector/ILspy shows me. They do not show the hex codes. But i see RVA for the method. Great!

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know ildasm had the bytes view! Also as an extra to your answer it seems that dumpbin is unnecessary as ildasm has a "headers" view that displays all the info required.

Comment: You see all that information in ILSpy (I used 7.0.0.6488)
If you open the file, expand metadata and optional header. Look for section aligment and file alignment, this correspondes to what is in Iridium's post.

To get the RVA in ILSPI simply switch from C# to IL view in the top menu. This will not only give you the RVA of any method, but when hovering over the opcodes it shows you the byte representation. Now you only to use a binary editor (I use open source FRHED) and you can look and manitpulate